# Extending a method in PHP

Tags: php, oop

I have two methods which are 90% identical, ie 90% repetitive code. I am trying to extend the 2nd method.

First Method:

```
public function getResultsByID($userID = null){
    $sqlParams = array();
    if (!$userID)
            {
                throw new Exception("No User ID Provided");
            }   

    $sqlParams['userID'] = $userID;
    $sql = "SELECT t.user_id,
                   t.owner_id,
                   t.store_id
            FROM users t
            LEFT JOIN store s
            ON s.store_id = t.store_id
            WHERE t.user_id = :userID";

    $db = $this->dbWrite : $this->dbRead;       
    $results = $db->getRow($sql, $sqlParams);

    return $results;

}
```

My Second method is pretty identical except that I am joining multiple tables into this.

```
public function getMoreResultsByID($userID = null){
    $sqlParams = array();
    if (!$userID)
            {
                throw new Exception("No User ID Provided");
            }   

    $sqlParams['userID'] = $userID;
    $sql = "SELECT t.user_id,
                   t.owner_id,
                   t.store_id
            FROM users t
            LEFT JOIN store s ON s.store_id = t.store_id
            LEFT JOIN owner_contact oc ON oc.owner_id = t.owner_id
            LEFT JOIN owner_detail od ON od.owner_id = t.owner_id
            WHERE t.user_id = :userID";

    $db = $this->dbWrite : $this->dbRead;       
    $results = $db->getRow($sql, $sqlParams);

    return $results;

}
```

I am unable to figure out how to extend my getMoreResultsByID() from getResultsByID() so that I can get rid of identical code

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont need to add two function to do same work all you need to do is pass parameter to function

```
public function getResultsByID($userID = null,$flag){
    $sqlParams = array();
    if (!$userID)
        {
            throw new Exception("No User ID Provided");
        }   

    $sqlParams['userID'] = $userID;
    if($flag=value1){
       $sql = "SELECT t.user_id,t.owner_id,t.store_id
        FROM users t
        LEFT JOIN store s
        ON s.store_id = t.store_id
        WHERE t.user_id = :userID";
    }elseif($flag=value2){
        $sql = "SELECT t.user_id,
               t.owner_id,
               t.store_id
        FROM users t
        LEFT JOIN store s ON s.store_id = t.store_id
        LEFT JOIN owner_contact oc ON oc.owner_id = t.owner_id
        LEFT JOIN owner_detail od ON od.owner_id = t.owner_id
        WHERE t.user_id = :userID";
    }

    $db = $this->dbWrite : $this->dbRead;       
    $results = $db->getRow($sql, $sqlParams);

    return $results;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @deepak, there is a small issue.. I am calling the getResultsByID() from many places.. now If I have to do this I have to pass $flag Value1 from everywhere.. where as the second query I am using is just once.. is there a way where I dont need to pass parameter everytime for the first query? can I just set one flag value for the 2nd query and put it in (if $flag== 1) and put the 1st query in else part instead of using elseif..? Thanks

Comment: @syed you right... I didn't knew your scenario. You will have to improvise my solution into your scenario.

Answer (score 5):

You could create another private method where you pass SQL query and userId as parameters like this.

```
<?php

private function queryResults($sql, $userID = null){
    $sqlParams = array();
     if (!$userID)
        {
            throw new Exception("No User ID Provided");
        }   

    $sqlParams['userID'] = $userID;
    $db = $this->dbWrite : $this->dbRead;       
    $results = $db->getRow($sql, $sqlParams);

    return $results;

}
?>
```

Then, you can use your methods like this.

```
<?php
public function getResultsByID($userID = null){
    $sql = "SELECT t.user_id,
                   t.owner_id,
                   t.store_id
            FROM users t
            LEFT JOIN store s
            ON s.store_id = t.store_id
            WHERE t.user_id = :userID";

    return $this->queryResults($sql, $userID);
}
```

Similarly, the other one. 
You can also modify your `queryResults()` method further, to serve other methods in your class.

Comment: Thankyou  @vishwa, I have removed the 2nd function and passing a flag value to the actual function. Cheers.!

Answer (score 0):

You can pass two parameters two the function `getResultsById`

```
<?php

public function getMoreResultsByID($userID = null, join = TRUE){
    $sqlParams = array();
    if (!$userID)
            {
                throw new Exception("No User ID Provided");
            }   

    $sqlParams['userID'] = $userID;
    $sql = "SELECT t.user_id,
                   t.owner_id,
                   t.store_id
            FROM users t";
    if (join){
        $sql.="LEFT JOIN store s ON s.store_id = t.store_id
                LEFT JOIN owner_contact oc ON oc.owner_id = t.owner_id
                LEFT JOIN owner_detail od ON od.owner_id = t.owner_id";
    }else{
        $sql.="LEFT JOIN store s
                ON s.store_id = t.store_id";
    }
    $sql.="WHERE t.user_id = :userID";

    $db = $this->dbWrite : $this->dbRead;       
    $results = $db->getRow($sql, $sqlParams);

    return $results;

}
```